# Javascript: benefit of setting subclass prototype from a function that returns an instance of the superclass?

Tags: javascript

I've been going back to basics with JavaScript principals lately and found a slight variation when extending a class that I am curious about. I know there are lots of options out there but I'm concentrating on just 1 to keep the scope of this question smaller.

Extending a class using a function to set the subclasses prototype:

```
function Shape(){};

function Square(){
  Shape.call(this, arguments);
  this.sides = 4;
}

function heir(p){
  function f(){};
  f.prototype = p;
  return new f();
}

Square.prototype = heir(Car.prototype);
```

Whats the difference between the above and setting the subclasses prototype in the following way?

```
Square.prototype = new Car();
```

The example using the `heir` function is taken from O'Reilly's Javascript "the definitive guide" book, so I'm wondering if there is a reason such a decent book used the above example over the simpler second example?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the polyfil for Object.create

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fcreate

```
  Child.prototype = Object.create (Parent.prototype);
```

Benefits are:

1: Parent constructor may need other complex objects to be passed that are not available when declaring Child.

2: Parent instance specific members are not on Child.prototype. Even though Parent.call(this... in Child constructor will shadow these members they still have no business being there.

More info here: [Prototypical inheritance - writing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711)